# Weak PYMC3 Estimates for Large Datasets

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I generated a dataset from a known Weibull distribution:
Weibull( alpha= A.SI^-n, beta) where A=1800, n=0.5, Beta=1.5, and SI=1000. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10nrRaQ3D8y4wt_qkL8T9P5lUmoE7HVvJ/view?usp=sharing) is the link of the dataset (DF1).
I tried to estimate the parameters of the distribution in a Bayesian analysis using PYMC3 and below is my code. The Bayesian estimates are very good when the size of the dataset is small (100 data points) but they get away from the true values when the dataset is larger (500 data points).
For the larger dataset I tried to get better estimates by increasing number of samples to 10000, tune to 10000, and target_accept to 0.99 but the estimates did not significantly change and still were far from the true values. I was wondering if anyone knows how to define the parameters of the pm.sample() to get better estimates for the larger dataset?

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd
import arviz as az
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt
from pymc3 import Model, Normal, Slice, sample
from pymc3.distributions import Interpolated
from scipy import stats

SI=1000

ns1 =round(DF1['biased drops'],2)
SIs=round(DF1['SIs'],2)

def logp(SIs,ns1,SI):
    summ1 = 0
    for i in range(0,len(DF1)): 
        print(i)
        F=DF1['failure'][i] 
        nu=(ns1[i])*(SIs[i]/SI)**n
        PDF = (B*nu**(B-1))/(A*SI**-n)**B
        R = np.exp(-(nu/(A*SI**-n))**B)
        logLik = (np.log ((PDF**F)*R))
        summ1 += logLik
    return(summ1)

with pm.Model() as model_ss1:

    MuB = pm.Uniform('MuB', lower=1, upper=3)
    SigmaB= pm.HalfNormal("SigmaB", 2/3)
    B = pm.Normal('B', mu=MuB, sigma=SigmaB)

    MuA = pm.Uniform('MuA', lower=400, upper=2000)
    SigmaA= pm.HalfNormal("SigmaA", 400)
    A = pm.Normal('A', mu=MuA, sigma=SigmaA)

    Mun = pm.Uniform('Mun', lower=0.2, upper=0.8)
    Sigman= pm.HalfNormal("Sigman", 0.16)
    n = pm.Normal('n', mu=Mun, sigma=Sigman) 

    y = pm.DensityDist('y', logp, observed={ 'SI': SI,'SIs': SIs.values.astype(int), 'ns1': ns1.values.astype(int)})
    trace_ss1 = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000, chains = 2)

Bi = pm.summary(trace_ss1, var_names=['B'])['mean'][0]
Ai = pm.summary(trace_ss1, var_names=['A'])['mean'][0]
ni = pm.summary(trace_ss1, var_names=['n'])['mean'][0]
az.plot_trace(trace_ss1, var_names=['B','A','n'])
```

Comment: @merv I updated the code and shared the link of the dataset. I have an incomplete failure dataset and cannot not use the regular form of the Weibull distribution to build the likelihood function.

Comment: You may have better luck here: https://discourse.pymc.io/

Comment: tried to access your DF1 dataset but blocked by Google Drive.. apparently not public

Comment: the first thing I would do is a prior predictive distribution check - visualising the distribution while increasing the number of simulations. You may then see if the prior choice treats extreme values as expected. If not, a stronger regularizing prior might be needed.

Comment: I could solve this issue by using more informative priors. I estimated the parameters using maximum likelihood and used the estimates as the mean value of the normal priors. Thanks!

Comment: "*used the estimates as the mean value of the normal priors*" - this completely undermines any results. Priors should not be informed by estimates from the data. You can use data to propose an initial value for MCMC chain, but not use it for prior parameters.